# Laravel update password only if it is set

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I am working on a laravel project with user login. The admin can create new users and edit existing users. I have got a `password` and a `passwordConfirm` field in the update-user-form. If the admin puts a new password in the form, it should check for validation and update the record in the db. If not, it shouldn't change the password (keep old one), but update the other user data (like the firstname).

If I try to send the form with an empty `password` and `passwordConfirm` field, it doesn't validate. I got a validation error, that the password must be a string and at least 6 characters long, but I don't know why. It seems like the first line of my update function will be ignored.

**UserController.php**

```
public function update(User $user, UserRequest $request) {

    $data = $request->has('password') ? $request->all() : $request->except(['password', 'passwordConfirm']);

    $user->update($data);

    return redirect('/users');
}
```

**UserRequest.php**

```
public function rules() {
    return [
        'firstname' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'lastname' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255',
        'password' => 'string|min:6',
        'passwordConfirm' => 'required_with:password|same:password',
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 7):

If you want to validate a field only when it is present then use `sometimes` validation rule in such cases.

Add `sometimes` validation to both `password` & `passwordConfirm`. Remove the `$data` line from `update()`;

```
// UserController.php

public function update(User $user, UserRequest $request) {

    $user->update($request->all());

    return redirect('/users');
}

// UserRequest.php
public function rules() {
    return [
        'firstname' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'lastname' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255',
        'password' => 'sometimes|required|string|min:6',
        'passwordConfirm' => 'sometimes|required_with:password|same:password',
    ];
}
```

Reference - https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#conditionally-adding-rules

Comment: It doen't work. After sending the form with an empty `password` and an empty `passwordConfirm` field, I got an error that the `password` field is required.

Comment: @Pengxer remove `required` from `password` & then check.

Answer (score 2):

I always do this in my projects:

```
//Your UserController file
public function update(User $user, UserRequest $request) {

    $user->update($request->all());

    return redirect('/users');
}

//Your UserRequest file

public function rules() {
$rules= [
    'firstname' => 'required|string|max:255',
    'lastname' => 'required|string|max:255',
    'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255'
];

  if($this->method()=="POST"){
   $rules['password']='sometimes|required|string|min:6';
  $rules['passwordConfirm']='sometimes|required_with:password|same:password';
  }
 return $rules;
}
```

So, as you can see if your method is **POST** it means that you want to add a new user so its going to ask for password and passwordConfirm but if your method is **PATCH** or **PUT** it means you don't need to validate password and passwordConfirm.

Hope it helps

Comment: It's a good answer. But it has a little loophole! What if the method is PUT (that means user wants to update) and the new password doesn't match the confirmation or it has fewer than 6 characters, etc? You have to check these constraints for PUT method as well.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should try the following:

```php
// ... more code

// Removes password field if it's null
if (!$request->password) {
    unset($request['password']);
}

 $request->validate([
    // ... other fields,
    'password' => 'sometimes|min:6'
    // ... other fields,
]);

// ... more code
```

Answer (score 0):

you should replace "has" with "filled" in your code

```
$data = $request->filled('password') ? $request->all() : $request->except(['password', 'passwordConfirm']);
```

and actually it's better if you use the expression like this

```
    $request->request->remove('password_confirmation');
    ( ! $request->filled('password') ) ? $request->request->remove('password'):"";
    ( $request->has('password') ) ? $request->merge([ 'password' => Hash::make($request->post()['password']) ]):"";
    //then you can use 
    $user->update($request->all());
```

Even better, however, you have to use separate request classes for create and update "php artisan make:request" for ex:
UserUpdateRequest.php and UserCreateRequest.php

for UserCreateRequest your rule is

```
'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
```

for UserUpdateRequest your rule is

```
'password' => 'sometimes|nullable|confirmed|min:6',
```

and your controller head add this line

```
use App\Http\Requests\UserCreateRequest;
use App\Http\Requests\UserUpdateRequest;
```

and your update method must change

```
public function update(UserUpdateRequest $request, $id)
    {
     //
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Standard way of doing this

**UserRequest.php**

first import **Rule**

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;
```

in your rules array:

```
'password' => [Rule::requiredIf(fn () => $this->route()->method == "POST")]
```

**Example:**

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => ['required', 'email'],
        'password' => [Rule::requiredIf(fn () => $this->route()->method == "POST"), 'confirmed'],
    ];
}
```

below **php 7.4** use this way

```
'password' => [Rule::requiredIf(function(){
   return $this->route()->method == "POST";
 })]
```